# Address reuse for business

Tags: address, address-reuse

The consensus is that address reuse is bad and should not be done. [Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse) even argues it hurts yourself and those who will own the bitcoins after you.

However, unless I am mistaken, most business reuse the same address all the time. They have to, to avoid having to generate a new address every time someone visits their website.

So I am struggling to reconcile this. Is address reuse actually ok? Am I wrong in saying that business reuse addresses? Or are most businesses creating a privacy issue in the block chain?

Answer (score 1):

This is more an issue of willingness. 
Generally you are right, address re-use is seen as "should not be done" :-) 
Biggest threat would be, that some bitcoins get "tainted", and loose their value. I leave it to the experts to get this explained. 
With HD Wallets you can generate enough adresses for your webpage/business usage. Just some coding required...

How many public/private keypairs can a Hierarchical Deterministic Wallets (BIP0032/BIP0044) produce? If I got it right, it should be some 2^31 addresses - probably enough for the majority of business cases.